# Why template for attribute is not processed

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

What I want to achieve is, when processor is at attribute node to wrap its value into `att` element.

This is the xml(input) file:

```
<planet-earth>
    <europe>
        <germany president="Joachim Gauck">Berlin</germany>
        <romania>Bucharest</romania>
        <france>Paris</france>
    </europe>
    <asia>
        <japan>Tokio</japan>
        <india>Delhi</india>
        <china>Pekin</china>
    </asia>
    <america>
        <brazil>Brazil</brazil>
    </america>
    <africa>
        <egipt>Kairo</egipt>
    </africa>
</planet-earth>
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <att>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </att>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I get as an output: `<root/>`. Instead I want this:

```
<root>
  <att>Joachim Gauck</att>
</root>
```

Why the template that matches all the attributes isn't processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is the same as doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />`. It does not select attributes, you need to explicitly do the following to ensure templates matching attributes are picked up

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
```

However, you don't have any templates matching elements in your XSLT. This means the [built-in template rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) for matching elements will apply, which is equivalent to this

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

In other words, the built-in template rule for elements is not selecting attributes, so you need a template

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <att>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </att>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```